# Jython When dmgr is down, how can we restart the application

Tags: websphere-8

on my server dmgr is down, how can I stop/start the application running on server1?

wsadmin script throwing exception.

Thanks
SF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If servers is federated, we can't connect to server directly. we need dmgr and nodeagent running to stop/start only application.

or

Server has to be standalone.

Thanks
-SR

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-host` and `-port` options of wsadmin to point to server1.

Alternatively, restart the dmgr.